# Reversing the order of button and dropdown inside input group in twitter bootstrap produces badly formatted result

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am attempting to "pretty up" a search a in my app.  It consists of a single textbox, plus a dropdown for selecting a "type" (analogous to "Sent Items", "Deleted Items", "Inbox" in an outlook type application),  plus a "go" button to execute the search.

I have prepared a fiddle below.  Notice that reversing the order of the dropdown and go button seems to have add space between the controls (which is not what I'd like).  Is this something I'm doing incorrectly in my html, or should I be logging this as an issue with the bootstrap people?

http://jsfiddle.net/ebV3v/

```
<form class="clearfix" role="form" style="padding:5px; border:solid 1px red;">
    <div class="input-group">
       <input id="searchText" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control" />
       <div class="input-group-btn">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="width:120px;">
               <span>[ -- Select -- ]</span>
               <span class="caret"></span>
           </button>
           <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
               <li><button>X</button></li>
               <li><button>Y</button></li>
               <li><button>Z</button></li>
           </ul>
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
       </div>
   </div>
</form>

<form class="clearfix" role="form" style="margin-top:5px; padding:5px; border:solid 1px green;">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input id="searchText" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control" />
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="width:120px;">
                <span>[ -- Select -- ]</span>
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                <li><button>X</button></li>
                <li><button>Y</button></li>
                <li><button>Z</button></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Place your `<ul>` element after the Search button, and the space is gone, and the dropdown list won't be affected.

I will investigate further and search for a way to leave the `<ul>` element there not taking this space. But my suggestion should solve the problem without affecting anything.

**EDIT**

It's not a `<ul>` problem exactly. The exact bug is caused by these buttons `inline-block` display, which comes from Bootstrap. As they are `inline-block`, any space between `</button>` and `<ul>` is taken as a text blank space. You should remove all spaces between them and it's fixed (I had to remove the line break between them in the source code too).

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ebV3v/1/)